# Need to update multiple collections on sailsjs

Tags: node.js, mongodb, collections, sails.js, insert-update

I did a component for manage categories weight and parents using nested lists . When i finished dragging i send a post with list serialized and i want to update the categories with the new options and send a Json with the status to the view. I tried to much things but any works. Now im trying to make a loop with a counter thats increments in each category update using Categories.update() callback but doesnt works. Any suggestion?

My code (data is empty and error is null):

```
var total = list.length;
var updated = 0;
var errors = [];
list.each(function(category){

    Categories.update({id: category.id}, {parent: category.parent}, function(err, data){
       updated++
       if(err)
        errors.push(err);

       if(updated==total)
          if(errors.length)
              res.status(400).json(errors);
          else
              res.status(200).json();

   });

});
```

P.D.: I tried also with setInterval for check updated and do the res.status...

Comment: What data are you expecting in the response?  You're sending `.json()` with no data argument.

Comment: Yes, i know, i will send a simple object with success true.

Comment: So what is your expected response, vs. what is actually happening?  It's unclear what your issue is.